# Invoking JBPM business process from Seam pageflow

Tags: seam, jbpm

I'm trying to invoke my business process from seam pageflow example. I have implemented NumberGuess pageflow example. I added myprocess.bpmn2 in component.xml file and myproject.jar file from JBPM into WEB\INF\lib of deployed war file.

```
<bpm:jbpm>
  <bpm:process-definitions>
    <value>myprocess.bpmn2</value>
  </bpm:process-definitions>
  <bpm:pageflow-definitions>
     <value>pageflow.jpdl.xml</value>
  </bpm:pageflow-definitions>
```

In pageflow.jpdl.xml, It is written as sub process.

```
<process-state name="Invoke">
  <sub-process name="myprocess"/>
  <transition to="displayGuess"/>
 </process-state>
```

Using: jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final,jbpm-6.1.0.Final,wildfly-8.1.0.Final as AS.
I'm not sure whether I'm on the right track. Can someone please help me invoke the business process from Seam pageflow.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the version of jBPM that seam used when integrating pageflow.  Since your example is jPDL, it's most like jBPM4 or jBPM3.  jBPM5 and after is now using BPMN2 as process language, it does no longer support jPDL.

Comment: Thanks Kris. So if I have to make it work with jBPM 6.1, I must add pageflow.bpmn2 in pageflow-definitions instead of pageflow.jpdl.xml ? How do I achieve this?